# Windows Server 2012 RDP: User Profile cannot be loaded

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I have done a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2 and did only the following configuration steps.
I have added a user and added the user to the preconfigured group of remote desktop users.

Now if I try to login with the created user the following error occurs:

```
Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded
```

The Windows Log got Warnings like:

```
Source  \\?\C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\computer.lnk 
Target  \\?\C:\Users\user.RS001055\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\computer.lnk
Error   Access Denied
```

There are at least 10 Warnings in which the System tries to copy files from the Default user to user.RS001055 and 10 warnings in which the System tries to copy files from the TEMP profile.

I am not sure if

```
\\?\
```

in the beginning of the path is correct. 
Furthermore the folder

```
 C:\Users\user.RS001055
```

does not exist. There is a folder called

```
C:\Users\user
```

It also does not matter if I add the user to the usergroup of administrators - I get the same error.

The machine is virtualized  (KVM).
Thank you!

Comment: Try to create a new user with administrator privileges and login with it. Make sure that no antivirus is running.

Comment: I've tried that. No antivirus is running, as i wrote it is a fresh install no programms installed extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting

```
C:\Users\Default\AppData\*
```

fixed the issue.